# Partial collisions for md5

Tags: collision-resistance, md5

Let $h$ be a bitstring and let $P(h, n)$ be the n-bit prefix of $h$. A partial collision of length $n$, for a hash function $H$ is a pair $(x,y)$, such that $P(H(x),n)=P(H(y),n)$.

What is known about this type of collisions? I'm particularly interested in md5. Can rainbow tables be adapted to quickly look for these? What values of $n$ are feasible to bruteforce (perhaps in an optimized way, like with rainbow tables).

I'd also like to know about the pre-image case: given $x$ and $P(H(x),n)$, how to find $y$ such that it's a $n$-partial collision for $x$.

Comment: Silly question: we know how to make total collisions with MD5; why are you interested in partial collisions?

Comment: @poncho: because it might be cheaper (?). Plus collisions don't solve the preimage problem.

Comment: Take a look at [HashCalc](http://hashcash.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H$ is secure in the [random oracle model](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/ro.pdf) and of width at least $n$, then $x\mapsto P(H(x),n)$ is also secure, inasmuch as an $n$-bit hash can be (proof sketch: any attack that distinguishes $x\mapsto P(H(x),n)$ from a random oracle is trivially turned into a distinguisher for $H$). The converse is not true.

---

Finding a [*collision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) requires $O(2^{n/2})$ queries to the oracle (or evaluations of the inner function of $H$). More precisely it is expected to require $o(\sqrt{\pi/2}\cdot2^{n/2})$ distinct queries, and odds of success reach 50% after $o(\sqrt{\ln 4}\cdot2^{n/2})$ such queries (that's the [generalized birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem)). The standard paper on how to exhibit such collisions is [*Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications*](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~paulv/papers/JoC97.pdf).

Finding a [*preimage*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) is expected to require about $2^n$ queries to the oracle (I plan to dig out the right formulas someday). It is possible to speed-up an attack by pre-computation, e.g. with [rainbow tables](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1063/555), in particular if the set of possible messages is known, or if $n$ is small enough.

---

Now we restrict to MD5, thus $n\le 128$.

The difficulty of finding *collisions* is about as for a good hash ($\approx 1.3\cdot2^{n/2}$ MD5 inner rounds) when the messages are tried without consideration of the inner structure of the MD5 round function (e.g. random messages or words from a dictionary). Without constraints on the message, finding collisions among messages of at least 1024-bit has been possible for any $n$ since that [breakthrough](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004), works even with some [constraints](http://www.di.ens.fr/~leurent/files/APOP_IJACT.pdf), now has [little cost](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006), and was [recently](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012) made possible with 512-bit messages. The lower $n$ is, the easier it gets. AFAIK there is no shortcut for heavily constrained messages, e.g. passwords of less than 10 ASCII characters.

The difficulty of finding a *preimage* is about as for a good hash (about $2^n$ MD5 inner rounds) when the messages are tried without consideration of the inner structure of the MD5 round function, nor knowledge on the origin of the target value. I am not aware of a practical method better than that, except when the message is in a known set smaller than $2^n$, which is when [rainbow tables](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1063/555) shine; in that case, I do not see that lowering $n$ changes the cost.